# angular2 url links in div body

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template

I have a `pre` block which is populated using interpolation:

```
<pre>{{text}}</pre>
```

and `text="some text https://google.com some more text"`

I want to get something like that:

```
<pre>some text <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">link</a> some more text</pre>
```

and as a result in browser I want to see only a hyperlink to the specified url:

```
some text link some more text
```

but if I try to inject html into text var for sure it will be shown as a plain text:

```
some text <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">link</a> some more text
```

Is there a simple way to get desired result? without using ngFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
text="some text <a href='https://google.com' target='_blank'>link</a> some more text"
```

And in your template:

```
<pre [innerHTML]="text"></pre>
```

Comment: thank you! It is so simple and obvious... and it work as I want